# How to toggle the link in my case?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to toggle a link  texts and content when user clicks the link.

I have something like

```
<a id='link' href='#'>click me</a>
<div id='items'>
   <h1>title here</h1>   
   <p>texts here...</p>
</div>

 $('#link').on('click', function(e){
     e.preventDefault();       
     $(this).text('isClicked');
     $('#items').empty().html("<img src='images/image.png'/>")
 })
```

When user click the link, the link text will become `isClicked` and the `items` html will be replaced with a image. However, if user clicks again, I want to see the link text changes back to `click me` and the `items` will hide the image and display the `title` and `p` tag contents again.

I am not sure how to accomplish this. Can anyone help me about it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Use a condition. if (text == "isClicked") -> restore. Else, change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a dummy class to the link and work with that condition

```
//Have a dummy class added to the link and toggle it on click
 $('#link').on('click', function(e){
     e.preventDefault();       
     var $this = $(this),
         $textDiv = $('#items'),
         $imageDiv = $('#image')
     if($this.hasClass('clicked')) {
         // remove the class
         $this.removeClass('clicked');
         // change the text 
         $this.text('click me');
         // Hide image 
         $imageDiv.addClass('hide');         
         // show text 
          $textDiv.removeClass('hide'); 

     } else {
         // remove the class
         $this.addClass('clicked');
         // change the text 
         $this.text('isClicked');
         // Show image
         $imageDiv.removeClass('hide');         
         // Hide text 
          $textDiv.addClass('hide'); 
     }
 });
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S8QCc/)**

You can also chain the methods applied on the same element.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#link').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).text() == "isClicked") {
        $(this).text("click me");
        .. etc
    } else {
        $(this).text('isClicked');
        $('#items').empty().html("<img src='images/image.png'/>")
    }
});
```

Like I said in my comment, use a condition like this. Simple and effective.

Answer (score 1):

One way you could do it:

```
$('#link')
//  Set data attribute to hold original text
.data('primeText', $('#link').text())
//  set click event using jQuery1.73+
.on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevents going to link, not needed if you set link href to "javascript:void(0)"
    //  begin setting text, within is a inline-if statement testing current text against prime text
    $(this).text($(this).text() == $(this).data('primeText') ? 'isClicked' : $(this).data('primeText'));
});
```

Another way, if you were working with more than one, like using a class name instead of ID:

```
$('.link')
//  jQuery's .each method allows you to do things to each element in an object group
.each(function(i) { $(this).data('primeText', $(this).text()); })
//  again, calling click method
.on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).text($(this).text() == $(this).data('primeText') ? 'isClicked' : $(this).data('primeText'));
});
```

## Examples

Answer (score 1):

What about using  a CSS approach?

Your HTML would stay the same:

```
<a id='link' href='#'>click me</a>
<div id='items'>
   <h1>title here</h1>   
   <p>texts here...</p>
</div>
```

But we can use .toggleClass() here to make our lives easier

```
$('#link').on('click', function(e){
     e.preventDefault();       
     $(this).text('isClicked');
     $('#items').toggleClass('display-image');
 })
```

The CSS would look like:

```
#items.display-image > h1,
#items.display-image > p,
{
     visibility:hidden;
}
#items.display-image{
     background-image:url("/images/image.png");
}
```

This way, you don't have to worry about removing things and .toggleClass handles their visibility.

You might have to do additional styling to get the image to work properly, or you may consider adding another element to contain the image and you can just set its visibility or display property

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<a id='link' href='#'>click me</a>
<div id='items'>
    <h1 class="text-item">title here</h1>   
    <p class="text-item">texts here...</p>
    <img src="images/images.png" alt="Image" />
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
img {
    display: none;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$('#link').off().on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if($('#items > img').is(':visible')) {
        $(this).text('click me');
        $('#items > img').hide(); 
        $('#items > .text-item').show();       
    } else {      
        $(this).text('isClicked');
        $('#items > .text-item').hide();
        $('#items > img').show();
    }
 });
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/warlock5658/Zv7Ec/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can try to store the value in a var and then toggle with on off in functions themselfs;

```
 var initialState = $('#items').html(),  
 functionBla(e) {
     e.preventDefault();       
     $(this).text('isClicked');
     $('#items').empty().html("<img src='images/image.png'/>")   
     $('#link').off('click').on('click', functionCla);  
 },
 functionCla(e) {
     e.preventDefault();       
     $(this).text('click');
     $('#items').html(initialState);  
     $('#link').off('click').on('click', functionBla);  
 };

 $('#link').on('click', functionBla);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like,

```
$('#link').on('click', function(e){
 e.preventDefault();       
 $(this).text('isClicked');
 $('#items').children().toggle();
 var img=$('#items img');
 if(img.length>0){
     img.remove();
 }
 else{
     $('#items').append("<img src='images/image.png' />");
    $(this).text('Click me');
 }


})
```